# Save document in a for loop using computeWithForm

Tags: xpages

I have the following button that can save multiple values in a for loop using computeWithForm

```
//to keep the code simple, I use hardcode value to save document except values in for loop  
var forloopvalues = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst", "myFieldValue1",2 );//use myFieldValue1 to lookup in the view
var date ="13/03/2017";
for(var i =0;i<forloopvalues.length;i++)
{
    var mdoc = database.createDocument();
    cdate = session.createDateTime(date);           
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "myForm");
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField1","myFieldValue1")
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField2", forloopvalues[i]); //suppose there are four values in the forloopvalues
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField3","myFieldValue3");
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField4", "myFieldValue4");
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField5", "myFieldValue5");

    if(mdoc.computeWithForm(false,false))
    {       
        mdoc.save(true, true);  
        getComponent("computedField1").setValue("Record saved"); 
    }
    else
    {
    }   
}
```

When I click the button, it can save the document. In the Lotus Notes Client, I can see there are four documents in the view. All the computed fields in the form also filled. However, I notice myField2 only saves the first value in forloopvalues not all values. So although there are four documents, both of them save the first value only in myField2. Therefore, if the computed field in the form that contains myField2 plus other values, it only show the first value in myField2 plus  other values

I review the code, there is forloopvalues[i] within the for loop and I don't understand why it only saves the first value only.

For example, assume forloopvalues are valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD. The myField2 only save valueA four times. If there is a computed field in the form that connect myField2 with other values together, the computed field value show valueA+othervalues four times.

I have another attempt, if I use document.save() + On document save in Run form validation in Data tab

In Lotus Notes Client to open the view and read the saved document. It will not show computed field in the form but the loop value is correct

For example, assume forloopvalues are valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD. The myField2 save valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD for each document. If there is a computed field in the form that connect myField2 with other values together, the computed field value show each forloopvalues+othervalues four times (e.g. valueA+othervalues, valueB+othervalues, valueC+othervalues, valueD+othervalues)

I believe computeWithForm is almost near the result although it save the first value in forloopvalues only. In Help Contents, I search about computeWithForm. It's syntax is 
    computeWithForm(dodatatypes:boolean, raiseerror:boolean) : boolean

and compare to the code in the application I think the syntax is fine. I double check the for loop and not understand why it only save the first value.

So how can I use computeWithForm to save the loop value. Thanks a lot.

update

I think computeWithForm is almost near the result because it can fill all the computed field in the form, but it saves one value in multiple times depends on the number of forloopvalues.

If forloopvalues has one value only, then it saves one time. It forloopvalues has three values, it save three times, each document (in myField2) contains the value of forloopvalues.

If I use document.save(), it can save documents for each value in forloopvalues individually but it will not fill the computed field in the form.

update

I try the following code to see if the value appears correctly inside the function

```
var forloopvalues = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst", "myFieldValue1", 2);
for (var index in forloopvalues) {
    if (forloopvalues.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
       makeAnewDoc(forloopvalues[index]);
    }
}

function makeAnewDoc(field2Value) {
    var mdoc = database.createDocument();
    cdate = session.createDateTime(date);
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "myForm");
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField1", "myFieldValue1")
    mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField2", field2Value);
    if (!viewScope.resultMessage) {
        viewScope.resultMessage = [];
    }
    if (mdoc.computeWithForm(false, false)) {
        mdoc.save(true, true);

        viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + forloopvalues[index]);
    } else {
        viewScope.resultMessage.push("Save failed for " + forloopvalues[index]);
    }
    // Bleeding memory otherwise!
    mdoc.recycle();
}
```

The result is when I click the button, the screen can show this message (suppose forloopvalues has four values)

```
Record saved valueA ,Record saved valueB ,Record saved valueC ,Record saved valueD
```

Due to the screen can show the forloopvalues, I feel strange why it only saves the same value four times.

Comment: That one is wrong: `viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + forloopvalues[index]);` it must read `viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + fiel2Value);` and your cdate needs recycling too. What @formula are in your form? Do they mess with the values?

Comment: In the form, in myField2, it is computed field. The formula is `x:= @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; "" : "" ; "CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst" ; myFieldValue1; 2 );
@If(@IsError(x);"no data";x)`, it just similar to `var forloopvalues = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst", "myFieldValue1", 2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Your code actually would save the last value. Don't loop through the values and save the same document 4 times. ReplaceItemValue can take an array as input. So you can use your lookup result directly. No loop required. Should be faster too</strike>

Did misread your question on tiny mobile screen. You need to change your loop slightly:

```
    var forloopvalues = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst", "myFieldValue1", 2);
    var mdoc; // In SSJS (ES3 there are no block level variables!)
    for (var index in forloopvalues) {
        if (forloopvalues.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
            mdoc = database.createDocument();
            cdate = session.createDateTime(date);
            mdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "myForm");
            mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField1", "myFieldValue1")
            mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField2", forloopvalues[index]);

             // Bind your UI field to a scope variable
             // don't access them directly 
             if (!viewScope.resultMessage) {
                 viewScope.resultMessage = [];
             }

            if (mdoc.computeWithForm(false, false)) {
                mdoc.save(true, true);
                viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + index);
            } else {
                viewScope.resultMessage.push("Save failed for " + index);
            }
            // Bleeding memory otherwise!
            mdoc.recycle();
        }
    }
```

or better: pull the function to save the document out (variables are function level in SSJS, not block level):

```
    var forloopvalues = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "CompetencyCourseViewCourseFirst", "myFieldValue1", 2);
    for (var index in forloopvalues) {
        if (forloopvalues.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
           makeAnewDoc(forloopvalues[index]);
        }
    }

    function makeAnewDoc(field2Value) {
        var mdoc = database.createDocument();
        cdate = session.createDateTime(date);
        mdoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "myForm");
        mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField1", "myFieldValue1")
        mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField2", field2Value);
        if (!viewScope.resultMessage) {
            viewScope.resultMessage = [];
        }
        if (mdoc.computeWithForm(false, false)) {
            mdoc.save(true, true);

            viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + index);
        } else {
            viewScope.resultMessage.push("Save failed for " + index);
        }
        // Bleeding memory otherwise!
        mdoc.recycle();
    }
```

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I try if I don't use for loop, it saves one document only.  I have to save document individually depends on the number of the forloopvalues. If forloopvalues are valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD, there will be four independent documents for each value in forloopvalues.

Comment: Sorry to bother you and thank you for the two options. I try both of them. They all can save documents depends on the forloopvalues and the screen can show the result like this `Record saved 0,Record saved 1,Record saved 2,Record saved 3`. However in the Lotus Note Client, I open the view. I can see the saved documents, it saves the same forloopvalues multiple times depends on the forloopvalues. In `mdoc.replaceItemValue("myField2", forloopvalues[index]` or  `makeAnewDoc(forloopvalues[index]);`, I try to remove `[index]` and the result is the same. Do you have any ideas on this issue?

Comment: For the second one: put a log statement into the function to see if your value appears correctly inside the function

Comment: I put the following code in `if(mdoc.computeWithForm(false,false))` `viewScope.resultMessage.push("Record saved " + forloopvalues [index]);` and `viewScope.resultMessage.push("Save failed for " + forloopvalues [index]);`. When I click the button, the screen can show each value in forloopvalues e.g. `Record saved valueA ,Record saved valueB ,Record saved valueC ,Record saved valueD`

Comment: I update the content to show the full code, I feel strange why it only saves the same value four times, but the screen can show each value in forloopvalues.

Comment: Does it save properly if you skip the `computeWithForm` ? If yes - you have @Formula in your form that mess things up

Comment: Sorry, do you mean if I skip the `computeWithForm` and use mdoc.save()? I tried but the result is more strange to me. there are seems 16 documents. I select any on document in the view, at bottom left, it shows 1 document selected . If I select all, it shows 4 documents selected. I guess maybe about each value loop 4 time, then 4*4 =16 so is that the reason I can 16 documents in the view but on 4 documents are actually located in the view?

Comment: If you don't do doc.save nothing will be saved back. Also a field should be either be computed by you or the form. The values get into each other's way - the formula will win at some time. Also check your view index. A document can appear more than once if the sort field has more than one value and the respective sort property is set. It looks very much you are trying to solve a problem

Comment: that you don't have when you design it NoSQL style. There's very little reason to generate multiple documents when fields can hold multiple values

Comment: In Lotus Domino Designer, I open the view, I notice there is one column has a tick in Show multiple values as separate entries. So I remove the tick, in the Lotus Notes Client. It shows 4 documents, not 16 documents. However, column that mapped to myField2, it display all values in one document e.g. valueA ,valueB ,valueC ,valueD. So if there are four documents, the column shows all values in each document.

Comment: If I select a document and double click to open it, I see the myField2 uses semicolon for multiple values (different in the view as it uses comma). I remember the reason that one column has a tick in Show multiple values as separate entries is I try to divide the myField2 value into separate documents. That column is mapped to a computed field in the form that myField2 value plus other values.

Comment: Your @Formula in the form does that. If you compute a field in your code, don't let the form compute again. Set your formula for myField2 to computed when composed with the value myField2. This way your form doesn't interfere with your code

Comment: Thanks for telling me to set myField2 to `computed when composed`. It works properly now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you see to be new to the Notes side of XPages, you might want to checkout my article series: https://www.wissel.net/blog/2013/12/domino-development-back-to-basics-overview.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your article series. I vote your comment because the link is useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

ComputeWithForm broke at some point in the Domino 9.0.1 fix pack cycle. Not sure which FP broke it. IBM has confirmed this issue and is looking at a fix. The onload, onsave, and both options do not work. SPR #LHEYAKALAH

Comment: Document.computeWithForm didn't break when you use it in code. But that's a stop GAP in any case

Comment: I didn't try the code version but the setting on the document data source is broken (ignored...)